# Play video using testCafe on mobile

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to test are webpage on mobile and its clicking the play button on a video but not playing the video. It runs fine on desktop browsers. I have tried the following commands `testcafe remote test/testCafe/was_test.js -e --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` below is my code that is used to click the play button.

```
test('see if video plays', async t => {
        await t.wait(10000) //this is to wait for the page to load
        data = await getdata()
        const playButton = await Selector('.plyr__control--overlaid')
        await t.click(playButton)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Remote browsers do not support specifying arguments in this manner. See:

[Start a Browser With Arguments](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#start-a-browser-with-arguments)

[Browsers on Remote Devices](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/browsers.html#browsers-on-remote-devices)

You might want to toggle your browser's default options, e.g.:

[How to control audio and video autoplay in Google Chrome](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/06/how-to-control-audio-and-video-autoplay-in-google-chrome/)